# why am I getting payment_status as pending on paypal sandbox?

Tags: php, paypal

I am always getting a "Pending" [payment_status] response from paypal sandbox, that's why my code for inserting data to the db doesn't work at all. Whenever I do checkout and complete the payment, this is the response am getting from the returned data

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 12.00
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [item_number1] => 2
    [payer_id] => TRCLJTHLNCJ7Q
    [tax] => 0.00
    [address_street] => 1 Main St
    [payment_date] => 20:15:44 Jan 01, 2012 PST
    [payment_status] => Pending
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [address_zip] => 95131
    [mc_shipping] => 10.00
    [mc_handling] => 0.00
    [first_name] => Test
```

it's always pending, when everything with regards to payment was completed and the test account overview itself, is showing the payment was completed.

that's why this part of the code, doesn't work at all because of the "Pending" thing

```
if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    if ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed'
          && no_paypal_trans_id($_POST['txn_id'])
            && $paypal_email == $_POST['receiver_email']
            && $paypal_currency == $_POST['mc_currency']
            && payment_amount_correct($shipping, $_POST)
            )
    {
     // process payment
         create_order($_POST);

    }

}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

any ideas how to fix this ? or why is this happening on the paypal's returned response ?

Comment: does this happen when the currency is the same? (if you are asking for dollars and he pays in euros the status is going to be pending I think)

Comment: am only using dollars, and i don't know what it is giving me a pending status when on sandbox , it was completed already

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turn off 'Payment review' for the account on https://developer.paypal.com/ > 'Test Accounts'.

Note: This info is also available in the 'pending_reason' response, which will give more descriptive information why it's pending (as you may see this occur in the live environment for payment reviews by PayPal or echeck transactions as well).

Comment: I turned off the payment review..now i don't know what happened why am receiving the complete status..but stillthe data won't get inside the db table of mine...is there a way to get the error message from the paypal.php IPN file ?..like throwing an alert box to show the error why data is not getting inside the db ?

Comment: Write to a log at each step with error_log() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: I moved the insertion of paypal data to db, to another area of my site..the paypal.php thing is not working for me at all

Comment: How to disable payment review on the paypal live site...?

Comment: Payment review on the PayPal Live site happens for only a small number of transcations, and should typically not last longer than 24 hours. If you have an account manager with PayPal, you discuss it with them, but I don't believe it can be disabled.

Comment: Hey guys, am stuck for the past 2 days on this. tried every bit of advice here & every where else I could find....The only thing I have tried cause I can't seem to find is 'Payment review'...this what I have on the developer.paypal sandbox page:[developer.paypal.sandbox-account](http://ndroidians.com/pics/developer_PP_SandBox.png)

Answer (score 3):

After dealing with this problem a little & PayPal changing the UI,

Here are the exact instructions from **PayPal Merchant Technical Support**:

Thank you for contacting Merchant Technical Support.

Please try to follow the instructions below to turn off the Payment Review function for your Sandbox account:

- Go to [PayPal Developer Website](https://developer.paypal.com/)
- Log in to your developer account
- Click Applications
- Click Sandbox accounts
- Click on to the email address that you would like to turn off the Payment Review option and click Profile after it expand
- Click Settings
- And select Off for the Payment review.
- Click Close

**!!!** Make sure you are doing this on your **PayPal SandBox Merchant Account**!

& Thats what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Additional details + reasons for a 'Pending' transaction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037648/doexpresscheckoutpayment-or-execute-transactions-are-always-pending-why

Comment: i have change the setting as you shown but still getting the same payment_status = 'Pending' is there any thing else which i have to do for this to work properly

Comment: did you try @Robert's suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If the Sandbox Account that is receiving the payment is of type "Personal", then IPN will send payment_status=Pending.

Answer (score 0):

If "Payment review" solution provided by Robert doesn't work, another reason why it might happen is that your seller account has option to accept or decline payment if it buyer has unconfirmed address or different currency. In this case you need to login as seller and accept payment and you will get another IPN with payment_status=Completed

Steps:

1. open paypal sandbox
2. press "test accounts" on the left
3. select seller account and press "Enter sandbox test site" on the bottom
4. You should see all the payment with option to accept or decline each of them

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Sandbox Developer Account.
Click on the Test Accounts link.
You should see your Test Accounts on the right side of the screen.
Notice the Payment Review column.
If you see Enabled for your Accounts, click on it,
You should now see Disabled.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this info while sending wrong business email address:

> [pending_reason] => unilateral

If someone will have that too try changing your business (not your client / buyer but seller) email address.